# jQuery :nth-child not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using this code

```
$('.list-item:nth-child(5n)').after('<div class="clear"><img src="http://domain.com/image.jpg" width="780" height="80" alt="banner" /></div>')
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not working in IE8, IE9...

Comment: AFAIK nth-child isn't supported in IE8 anyways.

Comment: @pixelngrain Please post your HTML for the `.list-item` elements. Also post any messages you might be seeing in your console.

Comment: i check and not working in IE. dont know whts wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery handles `nth-child` in the absense of native browser support. It works just fine in IE7, 8 and 9+.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/Y3MP4/

Answer (score 2):

`nth-child` is not supported in IE 6-8. IE9 has support for it. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951390/nth-child-is-not-working-in-ie) for a possible workaround.

Comment: jQuery handles `nth-child` in the absense of native browser support.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there's something else amiss.  Your code should work even in IE6 - though IE<9 doesn't natively support nth-child, jQuery's selector engine (Sizzle) implicitly handles it for you.

Give this code a go:

```
<script>
$("ul").remove();
var ul = $("<ul>");
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  $("<li>", {
    "class" : "list-item",
    html : i
  }).appendTo(ul);
}
ul.appendTo(document.body);

$('.list-item:nth-child(5n)')
  .after('<div class="clear">Clear!</div>')
</script>
```

Do you see the "Clear!" remarks?  Even in IE6, you should...

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an script that you can upload in your js folder and add some conditionals in your header and nth-child will work in IE 6, 7 and 8. you can learn more [here](http://selectivizr.com/) and if you need to use rounded corners you will need to install this other script called curvycorners.js
They are really time saving. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery nth-child selector doesn't work in some corner cases that involve complex selectors in IE8.

Following needed to be modified in IE8.

```
//Works fine in IE9+, FF and Chrome. 
//dataColumn = jQuery('.table-header div.rf-edt-hdr + div table table tbody > tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)');
//headerColumn = jQuery('div.table-header > div.rf-edt-hdr table table > tbody > tr td:nth-child(1)');
dataColumn = jQuery('.table-header div.rf-edt-hdr + div table table tbody > tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(0);
headerColumn = jQuery('div.table-header > div.rf-edt-hdr table table > tbody > tr td').eq(0);
```

NOTE:nth-child is 1-index based. eq() is 0-index based.