# Can't make nth-child work with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have the following to alternate colors in a table:

```
#grid tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
#grid tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#fff; }
```

However, this works in Firefox, but not in IE8. After some research, I tried the following:

**CSS:**

```
#grid tr.odd    { background-color:#eee; }
#grid tr.even   { background-color:#fff; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    $("#grid tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
});
```

But it doesn't work (actually, it didn't even work in Firefox). Any ideas of what else I could do (without having to use a third party js, such as Selectivizr)?

Thank you!

Comment: `without third party js, such as Selectivizr`... you're already using using third party js with jQuery. Selectivizr is actually a pretty tiny little script to add on top because it uses the jQuery selector engine; you've got the bulk of the code that selectivizr would be using in your site already.

Comment: This is why we don't use IE8

Comment: What's your HTML? Can you reproduce the problem (or a simple representation of it) at [JS Fiddle], or similar?

Comment: I'm thinking that jQuery cannot use the CSS3 nth-child selectors because IE8 doesn't support CSS3.

Comment: @Charles: that would explain why the CSS doesn't work in IE8; but jQuery should be able to fall back to Sizzle to evaluate/parse the HTML to implement the selector. And that jQuery, as written, should *definitely* work in Firefox.

Comment: Ok, so I decided to give Selictivizr a try... But I'm pretty new to jQuery, Razor, etc and now I got confused: The Selectivizr website (http://selectivizr.com/) says that I need to add

Comment: My comment was truncated... So I was saying that the website says I need to add the declaration "<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>"... in the page <head>. But, I don't have a <head> tag!!! The application is developed using C#.Net and uses Razor, so where should I add the declaration? Also, my Scripts folder I have a bunch of jQuery files (jquery-1.7.1.min.js, jquery-1.7.1.js, jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js, jquery-ui-1.8.20.js, jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js, etc); how do I know which one to use as "src"? Thank you!

Comment: Of course you have a head tag, it's in shared/_layout.cshtml

Comment: There it this! thanks Robert! So I added the declaration to the head tag, but the colors still don't work in IE8! :( Maybe I'm choosing the wrong jQuery library... How do I know which one to choose?

Comment: @Anna: jQuery version: choose v1.10. (do not use v2.0, as this does not support IE8)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery :nth-child not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937474/jquery-nth-child-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Thank you all! I finally got it working with Selectivizr YAY!! (although I have this weird issue were it works for one page but not the other =S)

Comment: Okay, so now I have this issue: I have a Subscription page and a Configuration page and both of them have a table (<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="grid">). I added the reference to Selectivizr to my _Layout.cshtml page and I got the alternating colors working in the Subscription page, but not in the Configuration page. Any ideas of what could possibly cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using jQuery by looping through each tr element and adding the class based on the index being odd/even

I tested with my a test web app with IE8, then I copied my code from the test app to jsFiddle. Only to realize that jsFiddle does not work properly with IE8.

**[WORKING JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s448y/2/)**

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('tbody').children().each(function (index) {
        var row = $(this);
        if ((index + 1) % 2 === 0) {                
            row.addClass("even");
        } else {                
            row.addClass("odd");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>Col 3</td>
            <td>Col 4</td>
            <td>Col 5</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1 data</td>
            <td>Col 2 data</td>
            <td>Col 3 data</td>
            <td>Col 4 data</td>
            <td>Col 5 data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you Charles380 :) I ended up using Selectivizr though.

Comment: It ended up that all the other solutions I tried would work for one page, but not for the other, so I decided to try what you suggested. Worked like a charm in both IE8 and Firefox! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:
CSS:

```
#grid tr {background-color: red;}
#grid tr:nth-child(even),
#grid tr.even { background-color:green;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#grid tr:odd').addClass('even');
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't confuse `:even` with `:nth-child(even)`, especially where it's unnecessary to use one in place of the other 2) Combining the two selectors together won't work; you may as well ditch the `:nth-child(even)` from the stylesheet and just use the class selector.

Comment: Combining the two selectors together will let smart browsers be able to render the page immediately, while IE8 and lower will initially render the page unstriped and then when the entire document is ready, it will stripe it.

Comment: I have updated it to reflect that tr:even to tr:odd since it selects the wrong rows.  I might serve the same CSS to both (depending on how many broken things I need to fix up).

Comment: @Robert: I tried what you sugested and had the same issue I head with Selectivizr: it works for one page, but not for the other, but with different results though. What happens when I use your solution is: With IE8: the Configuration page shows the rows alternating colors, but the Subscription page shows the head of the table in red and all the rows in the body green. With Firefox: both pages are displayed with the head in red, and the rows in the body green.

Comment: If you only wanted the body rows to alternate, you just have to place `tbody` in the selectors.  For example, `#grid tr {background-color: red;}` becomes `#grid tbody tr {background-color: red;}`