# nth-child not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list and need every other item on it to change color and remove its margin. I used the nth-child and it works perfectly on everything but IE7-8. I know that they don't support nth-child so i used Jquery.

I found this: [:nth-child is not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951390/nth-child-is-not-working-in-ie)
and this: http://verboselogging.com/2010/01/17/making-nth-child-work-everywhere

I tried to implement them but it's still not working. You can view it here:
http://www.dffernandez.com/client_review_files/tests/nth-child.html

```
#prop-images-wrapper {
float: left;
margin-bottom: 0.6em;
background-color: #F00;
width: 340px;
margin-right: 5px;}

#prop-images-wrapper li:nth-child(2n+1), .difcolor {
margin-right: 0px;
background-color: #06F;}
```

--

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$("#prop-images-wrapper li:nth-child(2n+1)").addClass("difcolor");
});</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does this jquery expression works for you ?

Comment: Note: you can use `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using jquery to set the to nth child, just use jquery for everything instead of having a css block and code for jquery.

check out the following jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RjGpC/1/

in this following line

```
#prop-images-wrapper li:nth-child(2n+1), .difcolor {
```

just remove the `li:nth-child(2n+1),`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load jquery in your test page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6vnt/1/