# alert() in $.get Ajax not Working in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hey I am facing a wired prob regarding alert() in IE
I am using Jquery Ajax $.get to get data ....
here is the code......

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#save").click(function () {
         vars = "pg=13&";
         if ($("#parent_code").val() == "") {
             vars += "type=insert&";
         } else {
             vars += "type=update&";
         }
         vars += $("#parent").serialize();
         $.get("pgs/dpg.php", vars, function (data) {
             $(data).find("row").each(function () {
                 stat = $(this).children(":first-child").text();
                 if (stat == "Saved") {
                     if ($("#parent_code").val() == "") {
                         $("#parent_code").val($(this).children(":nth-child(2)").text());
                         $("#parent_date").val($(this).children(":nth-child(3)").text());
                     }
                 }
                 alert(stat);
                 alert(data);
             });
         });
     });
 });
```

The above function works n shows popup in all browsers except IE I don't know where I am mistaken..... please help.........

Comment: Anybody please help.....!!!!

Comment: I am Using Internet Explorer 8.0.7

Comment: and which version of jQuery?

Comment: @MikeB http://jsbeautifier.org/ to the rescue ;)

Comment: Holy ancient version of jQuery, Batman!

Answer (score -1):

Try this, should work on IE 8.

```
$(data).find("row").each(function () {
    var firstChild = $(this).children().first(),
    stat = firstChild.text();
    if (stat == "Saved") {
        if ($("#parent_code").val() == "") {
            $("#parent_code").val(firstChild.next().text());
            $("#parent_date").val(firstChild.next().next().text());
        }
    }
    alert(stat);
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: It didn't work my friend.........

Comment: do anyone have any other solution.........

Comment: Then u should hand us the response, really hard to understand what u like to do. Did u replace all ur code with this or only the code inside the success function? The this code should not break and the alert should fired, did so in my fiddle any way.

Comment: I have replaced my code with urs starting from
$(data).find("row").each(function () {
till
});
But the alert is not showing in IE 8.....

Comment: Hm, that strange. Maybe if you can tell me whats in the data variable. Can u add that to ur original post and what jQuery version ur  using?

Comment: I am using jquery.1.4.2.min.

Answer (score -2):

In the code you've posted you are missing a closing `});` at the end.

Anyway, you should probably use `var vars = ...;` and `var stat = ...;`, using the explicit `var` keyword to initialize the variables.

Furthermore, `:nth-child` selector is not supported in IE<9, but you can find some workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951390/nth-child-is-not-working-in-ie).

Comment: *":nth-child selector is not supported in IE<9"* - In CSS maybe but jQuery has no such limitation. See http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Is there any alternative.....

Comment: Anybody with some other solution.........!!!